# TeX Rendering via HTTPS

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax, https

I am curious, has anyone been able to get mathematics stack exchange to display TeX correctly when using HTTPS? TeX does not render for me when connecting via HTTPS but does when connecting via HTTP on mathematics SE. TeX renders both via HTTPS and HTTP on math overflow. Not sure if this is better listed as a feature request or bug or something else.

Comment: HTTPS is currently not supported, SE is still working on making everything work with SSL.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6198/no-latex-rendering-at-all

Answer (score 5):

When accessing a pages with MathJax via the HTTPS protocol, we now use the CDN specified by the [MathJax FAQ](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/faqs/#problem-https):

> **How do I access the MathJax CDN using a https secure connection?**
>
> The MathJax CDN utilizes Rackspace’s CDN service. Unfortunately, this currently does not offer https support for the default address cdn.mathjax.org. However, as an alternative, you can use the following unmapped address:
>
> https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
>
> While not as appealing as cdn.mathjax.org, this address is stable and safe to use. For more information, see our documentation.

So everyone should now be able to enjoy the beauty of quality mathematics notation whichever protocol they prefer.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that errors are being raised by mixed content on the pages; both images and active content.

I get a warning on loading images (this actually succeeds)

```
Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page "https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OseL.gif"
```

and an error on loading MathJax

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"
```

Perhaps whatever is done on MO can be implemented here.

**Update:** according to the comment by Davide Cervone, the same behavior exists on MO.  This seems to be a browser security issue.

Comment: Good to know. Out of curiosity, how did you view these errors?

Comment: @user40919: Firefox has a Web Console: "Tools > Web Developer > Web Console". I turned that on and loaded the page.

Comment: interesting, thanks

Comment: Additional details on mixed content at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-does-content-isnt-secure-affect-my-safety

Comment: See [my answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12424/7798) to a similar question.  It provides a userscript that loads MathJax from the MathJax CDN's `https` address when you load Math.SE from an `https` address.

Comment: Note that not all browsers restrict mixed content in this way, so those of you seeing math in MO with `https` URL's may be using one of those browsers.  In Firefox, I get the same "blocked loading mixed active content" message in MO as in MSE, with unrendered mathematics.